# How do you query an embedded document for something that is not equal to a value in mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

I know how to find embedded documents that equal a certain value using the following syntax:

```
Location.where("address.country" => 'USA').first
```

But how do you query for when it does not equal the value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can use standard mongodb [$ne operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24ne).

```
Location.where("address.country" => {'$ne' => 'USA'}).first
```

With mongoid you can use a little sugar

```
Location.where(:"address.country".ne => 'USA').first
#              ^ note the colon here. It converts string to symbol.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also,

`Location.where("address.country".to_sym.ne => ['Australia', 'India'])`